# Bool if 'a' or 'b'

Tags: c++, boolean

So i need to swap  certain  letters in the input text with 'z' but for some reason my check doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
bool CheckLetter(int x) {
if(nm[0][x] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o')return true;
return false; }
```

The problem is in the '||'. If I only keep the 'a' my program works perfectly. In this way it gives me only  something like this: 'zzzzzz'. Any ideas?

Comment: `nm[0][x] == 'a' || nm[0][x] == 'e' || ...`

Comment: `||` is boolean OR, not set union.

Answer (score 6):

`'a'` is not a boolean. `nm[0][x] == 'a'` is. Therefore, you need:

```
if(nm[0][x] == 'a' || nm[0][x] =='e' || nm[0][x] =='i' || nm[0][x] =='o')
```

Note that in c++, `'a'` != `0`, therefore it is equal to `true` and your if statement would always be true. The only character that is not true is `\0`, the null character which evaluates to integer `0`.

Answer (score 1):

//better yet

```
bool CheckLetter(char c) {
  switch (c) {
  case 'a':
  case 'e':
  case 'i':
  case 'o':
    return true;
  default:
    return false;
  }
}
```

or this:

```
bool CheckLetter(char c) {
  return (c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o');
}
```